# Area between circle equation and a line

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles

Find the area of common region expressed by two inequalities $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ and $x+y \leq -2$.

It is needed in phi constant, so I assume I need to change it into its polar equation, then substitute the line equation into the circle one. But I don't know how to get the meeting point of the inequalities.

Comment: Are you certain that it's $x^2 + y^2\geq 4$? That's unbounded and gives infinite area.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Substitute second equation for x or y and plug into first equation. Then you can solve the quadratic equation in one variable

Comment: The common area is $\pi - 2$.

Comment: Impossible, @Quanto, the first area is infinite and the second are is about half of that.

Comment: Considering your title I have changed the body of the question. Please check if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first inequality should be $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$. What you have right now for that inequality is basically all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ outside a circle of radius 2, which doesn't make sense. You can rearrange $x + y \leq -2$ into an expression for $x$ or $y$, then substitute it into the circle equation to find the points of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

The line intersects the circle at (-2,0) and (0, -2), because they satisfy

$$x^2+y^2=4$$
$$x+y=-2$$

It is easier then to visualize that the common region is just the difference between the quarter circle of area $\pi$ and the overlapping right triangle of area 2.

Thus, the area of the shaded region is $\pi - 2$.

[image]

Comment: Oh, it is simpler than I though, the problem in my math skill is that I seem to have a very inflexible point of view, and I don't how to cure that. Btw, can this question be solved using integration of its polar equation?

Comment: Not easily; it’d be cumbersome to use polar equation for a straight line.